Python pycaw encountering an AttributeError when attempting to use the Activate method on an AudioDevice object
I'm trying to set the microphone volume to 100% using the pycaw library in Python. However, I'm encountering an AttributeError when attempting to use the Activate method on an AudioDevice object. Here are the details:
Code:
import os
import time
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume

def set_microphone_volume(volume_level):
    devices = AudioUtilities.GetAllDevices()
    print("Found devices:")
    for device in devices:
        print(f"Device name: {device.FriendlyName}")
        if any(keyword in device.FriendlyName for keyword in ["Microphone", "Mikrofon", "Kopfhörermikrofon"]):
            try:
                interface = device.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
                volume = interface.QueryInterface(IAudioEndpointVolume)
                volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(volume_level / 100.0, None)
                print(f"Volume for {device.FriendlyName} set to {volume_level}%")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to set volume for {device.FriendlyName}: {e}")

while True:
    set_microphone_volume(100)
    time.sleep(5)

Virtual Environment Setup:
Create a virtual environment:
python3 -m venv mic_volume_venv
Activate the virtual environment:
.\mic_volume_venv\Scripts\activate
Upgrade pip and setuptools:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
Install the required modules:
python -m pip install pycaw comtypes
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\StaticMicVolume.py", line 43, in <module>
    set_microphone_volume(100)
  File "C:\path\to\StaticMicVolume.py", line 36, in set_microphone_volume
    interface = device.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
AttributeError: 'AudioDevice' object has no attribute 'Activate'

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
